# Java Cc tokens and parser

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javacc

I am writing a program in java cc where i am making a compiler. I have written a code in .jj file where i have defined tokens and parser but at the end of the file the program is giving an error don't know why. Kindly help me to fix this.

```
void Start () : {}
{
  (
      INTEGER_CONSTANT
    | STRING_CONSTANT
    | LOGIC_CONSTANT
    | NOT
    | IF
    | END
    | SUB
    | LET
    | CALL
    | THEN
    | CASE
    | ELSE
    | INPUT
    | PRINT
    | SELECT
    | STATIC
    | IDENTIFIER
  )*
  <EOF>
}
```

I have the following error:

> org.javacc.parser.ParseException: Encountered " 
>   "INTEGER_CONSTANT "  "|" "| "   "STRING_CONSTANT "  "|" "|
>   "   "LOGIC_CONSTANT "  "|" "| "   "NOT "  "|"
>   "| "   "IF "  "|" "| "   "END "  "|" "| " 
>    "SUB "  "|" "| "   "LET "  "|" "| " 
>    "CALL "  "|" "| "   "THEN "  "|" "| " 
>    "CASE "  "|" "| "   "ELSE "  "|" "| " 
>    "INPUT "  "|" "| "   "PRINT "  "|" "| " 
>    "SELECT "  "|" "| "   "STATIC "  "|" "| " 
>    "IDENTIFIER "  ")" ") "  "*" "* "" at line 91, column 7.

Comment: I think you just forgot to put angle brackets around the names of the token kinds.  E.g., it should be `<INTEGER_CONSTANT>` instead of `INTEGER_CONSTANT`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the valid declarations for all the tokens(in lexical specification section) used in the parser method, you need to use these tokens inside angular brackets. See below

```
void Start () : {}
{
  (
      <INTEGER_CONSTANT>
    | <STRING_CONSTANT>
    | <LOGIC_CONSTANT>
    | <NOT>
    | <IF>
    | <END>
    | <SUB>
    | <LET>
    | <CALL>
    | <THEN>
    | <CASE>
    | <ELSE>
    | <INPUT>
    | <PRINT>
    | <SELECT>
    | <STATIC>
    | <IDENTIFIER>
  )*
  <EOF>
}
```

> JavaCC parser rule declaration:

1.) **Direct String :**

*In this case you can use the string directly inside the parser definition method but this needed to be enclosed within the double_quotes.*

```
 void start() : {}
  { "a" }
```

2.) **Using the token defined in the lexical specification section :**

*Here to define the rule using the lexical tokens that needed to be included within angular brackets.*

```
 TOKEN:{
      < A : "a" >
     } 
     void start() : {}
      { <A>}
```

3.) **Using in-line token defintion :**

*Here we can declare the token inside the parser rule definition. This is legal but make the grammar less readable.*

```
void start() : {}
   { <A : "a" >}
```

4.) **By calling another parser rule :**

*we can also define the rule by calling the another rule as below.*

```
void start() : {}
  { A() }
void A() : {}
{ "a" }
```

Hope this will be useful...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because you used `(...)*` and maybe is `(...)+` because with `*` you are saying 0 or many times. I think that's why the error.